# Flask socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] No address found Error for chat app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

When I run my Flask Chat App, I get an error that says,

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] No address found
```

Here is my full code:
main.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET'] = "secret!123"
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")


@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print("Received message: " + message)
    if message != "User connected!":
        send(message, broadcast=True)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host="localhost")
```

index.html file in templates folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000")
        socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send("User connected!");
        });

        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(data));
        });

        $('#sendBtn').on('click', function () {
            socket.send($('#username').val() + ': ' + $('#message').val());
            $('#message').val('');
        });
    })
</script>
<div id="messages">       
    
</div>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message">
<button id="sendBtn">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried installing flask 2.1.3, but that didn't change anything and I couldn't find any syntax errors, so I don't understand what happened.